# Why is table-level locking better than row-level locking for large tables?

Tags: mysql, locking, table-locking

According to the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html):

> For large tables, table locking is often better than row locking,

Why is this?  I would presume that row-level locking is better because when you lock on a larger table, you're locking more data.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

from the (pre-edit) [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html)

> Slower than page-level or table-level locks when used on a large part of the table because you must acquire many more locks

use a row level lock if you are only hitting a row or two.  If your code hits many or unknown rows, stick with table lock.

Comment: I see.  So perhaps it would be better if it were phrased more like "for large resultsets, table locking is often better than row locking".

Answer (score 19):

- Row locking needs more memory than table or page level locking.
- Have to acquire many more locks with row locking, which expends more resources

From http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/MySQL-Optimization-part-2/

- Advantages of row-level locking:

  - Fewer lock conflicts when accessing different rows in many threads.
  - Fewer changes for rollbacks.
  - Makes it possible to lock a single row a long time.
- Disadvantages of row-level locking:

  - Takes more memory than page-level or table-level locks.
  - Is slower than page-level or table-level locks when used on a large part of the table because you must acquire many more locks.
  - Is definitely much worse than other locks if you often do GROUP BY operations on a large part of the data or if you often must scan the entire table.
  - With higher-level locks, you can also more easily support locks of different types to tune the application, because the lock overhead is less than for row-level locks.
- Table locks are superior to page-level or row-level locks in the following cases:

  - Most statements for the table are reads.
  - Read and updates on strict keys, where you update or delete a row that can be fetched with a single key read:
    `UPDATE tbl_name SET column=value WHERE unique_key_col=key_value;`
    `DELETE FROM tbl_name WHERE unique_key_col=key_value;`
  - SELECT combined with concurrent INSERT statements, and very few UPDATE and DELETE statements.
  - Many scans or GROUP BY operations on the entire table without any writers.

Answer (score 2):

A <strike>row</strike> Table level lock is better for a large table where major data modifications are taking place. This lets the system contend with a single lock on the table rather than having to deal with a gazillion locks (one for each row).

The RDBMS automatically escalates locking levels internally.

Comment: I think you mean "A row lock is better..." :P

Answer (score 1):

> Table locking enables many sessions to read from a table at the same time
>
> To achieve a very high lock speed, MySQL uses table locking

"I would presume that row-level locking is better because" [you lock less data].

First "better" is poorly defined in this page.  It appears that better means "faster".

Row-level locking cannot (in general) be faster because of contention for locks.  Locking each row of a large result set means the very real possibility of a conflict with another large result set query and a rollback.

Answer (score 0):

In general if you need to lock a lot of data then 1 lock on a big table is cheaper than a whole bunch of row level or page locks