# How to achieve Multiple Consumer Application for Shared Database (Multitenancy)?

Tags: java, database, multithreading, oracle11g, multi-tenant

Below `Snapshot` is current `application flow`.[image]

### **Current Flow**

When `user Logged` in at these **`multiple deployments`**, then respective `SMSAgent(java class) insert user info in database`, `SMSHelper` is a `java Scheduler` which reads data from database in its local queue,`send SMS` and then `update user status in database`.

### **Issue with this flow**

Now,In above scenario, **`Multiple SMS is getting send to Single User`** because database is common and both the notification helper takes contact details from database(which may be common) and send SMS to that user.

### **Existing Solution**

Currently, solution to this problem is only available in oracle 11g where select query has for update skip locked support.

### **Expectation**

How to achieve the same with all databases at application level and not at query level ?

Comment: you can add an additional column that indicates sms is sent so that if onc helper class send sms it will update that column then other helper class can check that column just before sending sms

Comment: @coreJavare i think u havent read that helper updates user status in database.

Comment: SMSHelper should check status of sent flag "JUST BEFORE" sending sms so it wont send other sms

Comment: @Mat Thanks, Is it fine now.

Comment: @coreJavare Suppose both the helper checked status simultaneously, then in that case too, multiple sms will be sent.

Comment: Row level lock will solve that issue

Comment: @coreJavare Row level locking is not good for large number of rows  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462643/why-is-table-level-locking-better-than-row-level-locking-for-large-tables

Answer (score 0):

First,you have to **RESERVE** the row by update and then do select.

Suppose u have 200 row,

so first you should do is **RESERVE** by some value which are unique by instance, also you could limit on no of rows updated in your query and then select the row which are reserved by your query

> UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET SERVER_INSTACE_ID=UNIQUE_VAL AND ROWNUM <= RECORD_RESERVATION_LIMIT
>
> SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE SERVER_INSTANCE_ID=UNIQUE_VAL

Through this approach, you don't need to obtain lock on row or table.